# Move list of messages (filtered message) in a folder to another folder

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, message, move

Is there a way to move filtered messages from one folder to another folder?
I already checked these two docs
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/message-move?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http and https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/mailfolder-move?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http .
On these documentions, its only demonstrate of how to move one message per action or move one folder(with all contents inside) per action.

Thanks

Comment: No, but you could batch move the Individual messages https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/json-batching. Depending on the number of messages your moving watch out for throttling https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/throttling

Comment: Hi @GlenScales, Yeah, that's the only option available right now. Thanks for your feedback and the recommendation.